# Save a text file replacing the regular expression from variable in python

Tags: python, cmd, expression, ping

I am using this code to save in a text file a ping command:

```
from subprocess import *

def run_cmd(cmd):
        p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
        output = p.communicate()[0]
        return output

test = run_cmd('ping www.google.com')

print(test)

with open('sample.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write('dict = ' + repr(test) + '\n')
```

This code save the text using regular expression like /r/n
But when I open the text file or print the variable - the text save in this way:

```
\r\nDisparando www.google.com [2800:3f0:4001:81b::2004] com 32 bytes de dados:\r\nResposta de 2800:3f0:4001:81b::2004: tempo=20ms \r\nResposta de 2800:3f0:4001:81b::2004: tempo=15ms \r\nResposta de 2800:3f0:4001:81b::2004: tempo=15ms \r\nResposta de 2800:3f0:4001:81b::2004: tempo=16ms \r\n\r\nEstat\xa1sticas do Ping para 2800:3f0:4001:81b::2004:\r\n    Pacotes: Enviados = 4, Recebidos = 4, Perdidos = 0 (0% de\r\n             perda),\r\nAproximar um n\xa3mero redondo de vezes em milissegundos:\r\n    M\xa1nimo = 15ms, M\xa0ximo = 20ms, M\x82dia = 16ms\r\n
```

Please how can I save in a txt file using this expression replacing in a line break?

Thank you

Please how can I save in a txt file using this expression replacing in a line break?

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve. You use `repr()`, that's why it save it this way. Also you need to decode if not want bytestring

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution

```
import io
import subprocess

def commandP(command):
    output = subprocess.getoutput(command)
    return output

def recordV(file, output):
    with io.open(f'{file}.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(output)


output = commandP('ping www.google.com')
recordV('test', output)
```